# Which users have the highest rep to total posts ratio?

Tags: discussion, data-explorer

**Which users have the highest rep to total posts ratio?**

I'm curious which users contributed the "least" (in terms of number of posts), but have accrued the most rep.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[Here's](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/856189/users-with-the-highest-rep-to-total-posts-ratio) my query:

```
SELECT TOP 50
   u.Id,
   u.DisplayName,
   u.Reputation,
   count(*) as [Total Number of Posts],
   u.Reputation/count(*) as Ratio
FROM Users u
join Posts p on p.OwnerUserId = u.Id
where p.postTypeId in (1,2)
group by u.Id,u.DisplayName,u.Reputation
ORDER BY Ratio DESC
```

Almost all of the top 50 users made only one post.

```
Id     |DisplayName |Reputation |Total Number of Posts |Ratio
13161  |mattshane   |34863      |1                     |34863
581625 |baisong     |28430      |1                     |28430
543858 |chuck97224  |26658      |1                     |26658
...
```

Details of the 3 posts relating to the users above follow

- mattshane asked ["What and where are the stack and heap?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/79923/73226). (Current score 6974)
- baisong answered ["src refspec master does not match any when pushing commits in git"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7572252/73226). (Current score 2827)
- chuck97224 answered ["Config Error: This configuration section cannot be used at this path"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12867753/73226). (Current score 2659)

Comment: "Almost all of the top 50 users made only one post." -- [A variation on the query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/856203/1057260/users-with-the-highest-rep-to-total-posts-ratio) which only includes users with a minimum amount of posts.

Comment: contributing with a question is even less contributing that with an answer... 35k gives almost the max delvotes & quick deletion rights. But those were ancient times.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre - Matt Shane was " Last seen Jan 23 '09" so these privileges gained have gone unused.

Comment: @duplode:  Thanks for your query. It's interesting to run it with the limits set at 100, 1000, 10000 posts.  John Skeet doesn't appear until the last (nor do I).  The most prolific posters don't get all that many points per posting.

Comment: @Jonathan, on the other hand, posting more will reduce your ratio, so prolific posters are actively working against what is being queried for here.

Comment: [Alternative Query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/856793) that tries to solve the "a single good post will propel you to the top" issue. It raises the ratio to the power of sqrt(sqrt(user_posts)) / average_posts_per_user. The fourth-order root was necessary to keep the numbers in the int range, and has the effect of squashing the values for the exponent a bit. You can change the 0.25 in that query to play around with other order roots. The net effect is adding some weight to the number of posts as well. It ain't perfect, but a good starting point perhaps?

Comment: Interestingly, if you flip the ratio [you get a list of suspended users](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/864760/users-with-the-highest-posts-to-total-rep-ratio)

Comment: Matt shane current score 82769, chuck: 34266

Answer (score 3):

Quoting [your self-answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/368664/2751851):

> Almost all of the top 50 users made only one post.

[Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/856203/users-with-the-highest-rep-to-total-posts-ratio) is a variation of the query which only includes users with a minimum amount of posts. As of now, out of the top ten users with at least ten posts, seven have ten or eleven posts. There already is more variability in that regard once the cutoff is raised to a hundred posts.